# .append: clear input value onclick

Tags: javascript, input

I have a bookmarklet that appends the body to bring up a little litebox. In that litebox there is a form. When the user clicks on an input field I want the current value to disappear. This is what I have tried so far and it isn't working.

```
function runthis() {
$('body').append("<p><input type='text' name='story_price' value='Price' onClick='this.value=''' /><p>");}
```

I have also tried this and it doesn't allow my bookmarklet to show up:

```
function runthis() {
$('body').append("<p><input type='text' name='story_price' value='Price' onClick='this.value=""' /><p>");}
```

Any thoughts on how I could possible clear the contents within the .append

Thanks!

Comment: Escape your quotes - \' or \"

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!. Final code: function runthis() {
$('body').append("<p><input type='text' name='story_price' value='Price' onClick=\"this.value=''\" /><p>");}

Comment: Not optimal. Please see my answer for a better version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your quotes

("It is 'OK' to use single quotes inside double")

('This isn't OK') - should be ('This isn\'t OK')

```
function runthis() {
$("body").append('<p><input type="text" name="story_price" value="Price" onClick="this.value=\'\'" /><p>');}
```